# OrderBy a column in another table having multiple columns

Tags: c#

I have a query like below,

```
IQueryable<ProductParent> = 
      unitOfWork.GetRepository<ProductParent>()
                .GetTable()
                .Expand<ProductParent, ICollection<ProductChild>>((Expression<Func<ProductParent, ICollection<ProductChild>>>)(i => i.ProductChild));
```

I have to apply order by [Name] in `[ProductChild]` to this query.

There will be multiple values in `ProductChild` table.

Comment: What is `GetTable`? What is `Expand`?